# question about infimun

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ a open set and $p >1$. Let $K \subset \Omega$ a compact set. 
Define 
$$A:= \{ u \in C^{\infty}_{0} (\Omega) ;  \ u \geq 1 \text{ on } K\}$$

$$ B:= \{ u \in C^{\infty}_{0} (\Omega) ;  \ u \geq 1 \text{ on } \partial K\}$$

Show that

$$ \inf_{u \in A} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u |^p \ dx = \inf_{u \in B} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u |^p \ dx$$

A good time ago i tried to prove this and i only proved the obvious inequality (first inf $\geq$ second inf)...

Someone can give me a hint ?

Comment: *Equivalence of two definitions of capacity* would be a far better title. Think of this question being in the archive alongside hundreds of questions about infima and suprema in real analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $u\in B$, observe that $u$ is  Lipschitz on an open set containing $K$. So is $\tilde u=\max(u,1)$, and this truncation does not increase the norm of gradient. Next, let $v=1$ on the interior of $K$, and $v= \tilde u$ otherwise. The Lipschitz condition survives.  Therefore, $v\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$. Let $\psi $ be a compactly supported smooth function with small $W^{1,p}$ norm such that $\psi >0$ on $K$. 
Mollifying $v+\psi$, we get a function $w\in C_0^\infty$ such that $w>1$ on $K$ and $\|w-\tilde u\|_{W^{1,p}}$ is small. Since $w\in A$, and $\int|\nabla w|^p$ is not much larger than $\int|\nabla u|^p$, the statement follows.

Comment: can you say to me  a good book about capacity theory? (my english is terrible, sorry..)

Comment: @LeandroTavares There are different approaches to capacity: via energy of measures and via Dirichlet integral, as in your question.  The energy approach, see [Landkof](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZUpxMQEACAAJ) or [Armitage-Gardiner](http://books.google.com/books?id=02p9FQ41o9cC). For the Dirichlet integral approach, see [Heinonen-Kilpelainen-Martio](http://books.google.com/books?id=pp0HXuZd7R8C). Be advised that these books are not exclusively about capacity; it is merely a tool for doing something else.

Comment: @LeandroTavares One more: section 4.7 in *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* by Evans and Gariepy. It's not long, but it covers the main points.